# Convergence of subsequence proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence with $a_n\rightarrow a$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Prove that $a_{2n}\rightarrow a$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ also.
I'm not sure about my proof - can someone check this for me?

My attempt: By definition of convergence, for all $n\geq N_\epsilon$ we have $|a_n-a_|<\epsilon$. Rearranging gives $a-\epsilon<a_n<a+\epsilon$ for all $n$. Consequently we have $a-\epsilon<a_{2n}<a+\epsilon$, as $a$ is fixed. Once again rearranging yields $|a_{2n}-a|<\epsilon$, which proves the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to 'rearrange'. Just use $2n \geq n \geq N_\varepsilon$. But yes, you are right.

If $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges, all subsequences have the same limit.